# Add jquery to a html element that is added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I have `<video>` elements added to the page when an image is clicked. A light box with the video pops up. What would be the best way to execute a snippet of jquery to this dynamic video element? I though maybe some form of the `.on` method might work was not sure.

Edit: I'm using [ilightbox](http://ilightbox.net/documentation.html#options) for the lightbox which has code that adds in a html video after a lightbox image is clicked.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Please post the code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

[.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) working good for new element in Document object model(DOM)

The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/),  [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), and [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/). To remove events bound with .on(), see [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself, see [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

reference **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**